# How can I use android-room to insert nested objects to a separate table entity? I do not want the nested object to be @Embedded

Tags: java, android, sql, kotlin, android-room

This is the complex object

```
@Entity(tableName = "localization_data")
data class LocalizationData(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "key")
    val key: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "text")
    val texts: Array<TextData>,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_updated")
    val lastUpdated: Date
)

@Entity(
    tableName = "text_data",
    foreignKeys = arrayOf(
        ForeignKey(
            entity = LocalizationData::class,
            parentColumns = ["key"],
            childColumns = ["text_id"]
        )
    )
)
data class TextData(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "text_id")
    val textId: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "text")
    val text: String,
    @Embedded(prefix = "textdata_")
    val language: LanguageData
)
```

`TextData` is an entity as well and I want that is attached to `LocalizationData` and is identified by the `key` field. I want to store `TextData` in a the `LocalizationData` table and in a separate table as well when an @Insert function is call from LocalizationDOA. Also I want to be able to access `TextData` entity from TextDOA

Comment: how about use [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction] transaction